# Multiple compound assignment statements with parentheses C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

I am trying to learn C++ by coding a simple class to take an input of two doubles, a real and imaginary part, and perform operations on them. I have one section in particular,

```
cout << "((c1 += c2) += c3) = " << ((c1 += c2) += c3) << endl; 
cout << "c1 = " << c1 << endl;
```

In this case, it correctly prints what the sum of c1, c2, and c3 is, but c1 only updates to the sum of c1 and c2. I'm wondering why that is the case.

Comment: your statement says: `c1 += c2` -- what value of `c1` do you expect?

Comment: Just to clarify, `a += b` means `a = a+b`

Comment: I'm expecting a value of c1 that is the sum of c1, c2, and c3.

Comment: i used MSVC2015 and GCC 8.2.1 in both compilers: c1 updates to sum of c1, c2 and c3 with your code

Comment: http://cpp.sh/3rjdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `((c1 += c2) += c3)` in this code first of all inner bracket will be executed which is `(c1+=c2` this will give sum of c1 and c2 after which it will be added with c3 `(c1+c2)+=c3` will add c3 to the sum. 
Since c3 is added to the sum  of c1 and c2 and not to the variable c3.  Therefore c1 only have sum of c1 and c2 only.
If you want want c1 to have sum of c1 ,c2 and c3 as well then try this `((c1=(c1 += c2)) += c3)`

Hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`(c1 += c2)` will return c1 and add c2 to c1. Then, since c1 is returned, the statement changes to `c1 += c3`. So then, c3 is added to c1. By this logic, c1 should be equal to the sum of the initial values of c1, c2, and c3.